# Look up Drop Down field getting Populated but showing "none" by default. Fetched value needs to be selected

Tags: sharepoint-designer, lookup-column

How to select the single populated choice by-default instead of 'none'.

[image]

Comment: This screenshot looks strange. If Specialist is a required field, (none) should not be an option.

Answer (score 2):

Go to List Settings, Click the name of your drop down column. Under Additional Columnt Settings "Default Value"
[image]

Comment: It is a lookup column so these additional settings are not available.